# Map a Collection of Objects by property in Java

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a custom Class like this:

```
public class Client {
    public int ID;
    public String Name;
    public double buys;
    public double getBuys() {
        return this.buys;
    }
}
```

Then, I have defined a list of Client, like:

```
List<Client> clientList;
```

Let's say that that List has a lot of client objects, already initialized. How can I map the field "buys" of each client object using Java 8?

I've tried something like:

```
List<Client> clientList2 = clientList.stream().map(c.getBuys() -> c.getBuys() + 1).collect(Collections.toList());
```

It, of course, isn't working, but i can't figure out (or find) any way to do it. What I want to do is just to modify every "buys" value of each object of the list. In the example case, I'm adding one, but it could be any operation.

Comment: Do you want to add 1 to the buys of each Client?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do with the `buys` field. What should the output look like?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "map" here? It seems that you want to get a list of client with a existing list. But what do you want the new list to be?

Comment: Sorry for been uncleared guys. Thank you for your comments anyway.
What i want to do is just modify every buys value of each object of the list. In the example case, adding one, but it could be any operation.

Comment: It would be very easy to make a new list where the clients are new objects with incremented `buys` fields. Alternatively, If you want to mutate the existing client objects you would use `forEach` not `map`.

Comment: Could you tell me exactly how, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comment, what you want is to modify the buys of each client by applying a custom function. Consider the following method:

```
private static List<Client> mapClients(List<Client> clients, DoubleUnaryOperator op) {
    return clients.stream()
                  .peek(c -> c.setBuys(op.applyAsDouble(c.getBuys())))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

or the following simple `for` loop:

```
private static List<Client> mapClients(List<Client> clients, DoubleUnaryOperator op) {
    for (Client client : clients) {
        client.setBuys(op.applyAsDouble(client.getBuys()))
    }
    return clients;
}
```

This method will mutate every Client and set the buys with the result of the operator (a [`DoubleUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleUnaryOperator.html) is an operator that takes a `double` as argument and returns a value of type `double`). The operator is getting the buys as input to make the calculation. Then, you could use it like this:

```
mapClients(clients, d -> d + 1); // every buys are added 1
mapClients(clients, d -> 2*d); // every buys are multiplied by 2
```

Note that this solution **mutates** an existing Object, which is not a nice practice. It would be better to have a constructor of Client taking the buys as input and mapping the result of the operation to a new Client, like this:

```
private static List<Client> mapClients(List<Client> clients, DoubleUnaryOperator op) {
    return clients.stream()
                  .map(c -> new Client(op.applyAsDouble(c.getBuys())))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a `for` loop.

```
for (Client client : clientList)
    client.setBuys(client.getBuys() + 1);
```

Comment: In case of having a large amounts of clients in the list, would it be efficient enough?

Comment: You could use parallelism like this: `clientList.parallelStream().forEach(c -> { c.setBuys(c.getBuys() + 1); });`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Iterator provided by Java?

```
for( Client c: clientList){ 
System.out.println(c.getBuys());
}
```

Or add the result to a map or whatever.

Comment: Same questions, in case of having a large amounts of clients in the list, would it be efficient enough?

Comment: I think this feature is optimized at low level, but i don't know if it could be better on specific collection (LinkedList, Maps, ecc). But I think it's always good to use foreach statement.